# Accessing another UIViewRepresentable's controller or UIView

Tags: swiftui, uikit

`UIViewRepresentable` is useful for bringing UIKit views into SwiftUI context. Their primary limitation is that the instantiation of the UIKit side of things is not under our control - it happens as-needed by the SwiftUI subsystem.

This creates difficulties when two UIViews need to have knowledge of each other in order to collaborate. An example could be an `MKMapView` and an `MKCompassButton`. The latter needs an instance of the former to sync with.

Passing such a reference between separate `UIViewRepresentable` values is difficult since the controller or view is not available to us directly.

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView { .init() }
}
struct CompassButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKCompassButton { .init(mapView: ???) }
}
/// or
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let compass = CompassButton()

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView { .init() }

    struct CompassButton: UIViewRepresentable {
        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKCompassButton { .init(mapView: ???) }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know of a mechanism by which we can allow two SwiftUI views based on `UIViewRepresentable` to collaborate using their underlying UIKit views, perhaps through sharing a controller instance, or other means?

My first thought would be to move the instantiation of the controller out of `makeController` and into the `UIViewRepresentable` directly as a `var`, but this would likely interfere with the SwiftUI life-cycle management of the controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't access the internals of a `UIViewRepresentable` and if you hold on to the `UIView` variable you'll start getting the "updating view while updating view isn't allowed error" that is quite popular. Apple just doesn't allow access to internals with SwiftUI.

Creating a common "ViewModel"/Controller that is shared between UIKit and SwiftUI is the simplest way to do this. The `UIView`'s would exist in a `UIViewController` so you get all the UIKit benefits.

```
import SwiftUI
import MapKit
///Source of truth for both SwiftUI and UIKit
class MapCompassViewModel: ObservableObject, MapController{
    @Published var provider: (any MapProvider)?
    
    func toggleCompassVisibility(){
        provider?.toggleCompassVisibility()
    }
    func addCompass(){
        provider?.addCompass()
    }
}
```

You can use `protocols` to hide the internal implementations.

```
protocol MapProvider{
    var map : MKMapView {get set}
    func toggleCompassVisibility()
    func addCompass()
}
protocol MapController{
    var provider: (any MapProvider)? {get set}
}
```

The UI part is just a `View` a `UIViewControllerRepresentable` and a `UiViewController`.

```
///Plain SwiftUI View
struct MapCompassView: View {
    @StateObject var vm: MapCompassViewModel = .init()
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            //This is needed to for the very first frame,
            //when we are waiting for the provider
            //to be set for the UIViewController
            if let provider = vm.provider {
                Compass_UI(provider: provider)
                    .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
            }
            Button("Show/Hide compass", action: vm.toggleCompassVisibility)
            MapCompass_UI(vm: vm)
        }
    }
}
///Converts UIKit `UIView` to a `UIViewRepresentable`
struct Compass_UI: UIViewRepresentable{
    let provider: any MapProvider
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> some UIView {
        let m = MKCompassButton(mapView: provider.map)
        m.compassVisibility = .visible
        return m
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
///Converts UIKit `UIViewController` to a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`
struct MapCompass_UI: UIViewControllerRepresentable{
    let vm: any MapController
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        MapCompassViewController(vm: vm)
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
///Regular `UIViewController` that uses `MapCompassViewModel`
///This can be as complex as needed.
class MapCompassViewController: UIViewController, MapProvider{
    var vm: any MapController
    lazy var map: MKMapView = {
        let m = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
        m.showsCompass = false
        return m
    }()
    lazy var compass: MKCompassButton = {
        let m = MKCompassButton(mapView: map)
        m.frame.origin = .init(x: 20, y: 20)
        m.compassVisibility = .visible
        return m
    }()
    init(vm: any MapController) {
        self.vm = vm
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        //Critical connection between SwiftUI and UIKit
        DispatchQueue.main.async{
            self.vm.provider = self
        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //Add map
        view.addSubview(map)
        //Pin map to edges
        map.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        map.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        map.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        map.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        map.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        //Add compass
        map.addSubview(compass)
    }
    func toggleCompassVisibility(){
        compass.compassVisibility = compass.compassVisibility == .visible ? .hidden : .visible
    }
    func addCompass() {
        print("\(#function) :: add your compass code")
    }
    deinit{
        vm.provider = nil
    }
}
struct MapCompassView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        MapCompassView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice work. Perhaps with a little adjustment we can expose access to the `MKMapView` through the `MapController`, since keep in mind that the original intent of the question is to access a `UIView` reference from two separate SwiftUI `View`s. Concretely, imagine wanting to place the `Map_UI` in one location in your SwiftUI hierarchy and the `Compass_UI` in a different location in the SwiftUI hierarchy, while they continue to share a link to the same underlying `MKMapView` reference. Currently the two are stuck in the same hierarchy through `UIKit.UIView.addSubview`

Comment: @Ihunath it can be easily exposed by just adding the variable to the `MapProvider`, I added it to the code above. I would just be careful of adding any wrappers that would trigger `update` in the `Compass_UI`SwiftUI is. very particular when it comes to wanting ownership with `UIView`s and `UiViewController`s

Comment: @Ihunath, I have made a few changes to the code let me know what you think.

Answer (score 3):

Besides **WHY** you need to make this kind of circular reference without using a *coordinator*, wrapper or other methods, here is your answer:

1. add a way to get the dependency from outside:

```
struct CompassButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    weak var mapView: MKMapView? //  Get it from outside (weak for avoiding leak)
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKCompassButton, context: Context) { uiView.compassVisibility = .visible }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKCompassButton { .init(mapView: mapView) }
}
```

2. Make the dependency visible to outside:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    private (set) var mapView: MKMapView = .init() //  make it visible
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView { mapView }
}
```

3. Keep a reference and use it later:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let mapView = MapView() //  Keep a reference
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            mapView
            CompassButton(mapView: mapView.mapView) //  Use the reference
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}
```

I don't think this is the way you should make it happen but I think this is what you are looking for

Comment: If this strategy were used at the very top level of the view hierarchy where it is never reloaded, I can see how it might be doable, but if not, doesn't `private (set) var mapView: MKMapView = .init()` guarantee that a *new* instance of `MKMapView` will be created on every pass through he hierarchy?

Comment: You should `make it visible`. The responsibility of keeping the pointer is on you and depends on the use case

Comment: You'll probably at least want `@State` on that `var mapView: MKMapView`, to make sure the `ContentView` value-type properly manages the lifecycle of the `MKMapView` reference type.

Comment: One ongoing concern I have is that `makeUIView` may want control over the life-cycle of the `UIView`. In this solution, the `UIView`'s lifecycle is externalized and SwiftUI is no longer in control. Eg. if it for whatever reason wants the `UIView` to be destroyed and later a new one created, it can no longer do this.

Comment: SwiftUI can remove the entire MapView struct including all references inside it. Also, there is no such a thing as life cycle of view in SwiftUI. `View` is just a protocol and its based on its State! This is why **you** should keep it safe from recreating or etc

Comment: There is no question about the life cycle of a `SwiftUI.View`. There is a question about the life cycle of the `UIKit.UIView` that the SwiftUI view representable manages state for. Your solution is fighting with the internal SwiftUI ownership over the `MKMapView`'s life-cycle.

Answer (score 2):

To directly address your question as asked, you can keep state at a level above both views (ie a parent). This, for example, works:

```
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    var mapView = MKMapView()
}

@main
struct CustomCardViewApp: App {
    @StateObject var appState = AppState()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContainerView(mapView: appState.mapView)
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    var mapView: MKMapView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView { mapView }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
}

struct CompassButton: UIViewRepresentable {
    var mapView: MKMapView
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKCompassButton {
        let button = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapView)
        button.compassVisibility = .visible
        return button
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKCompassButton, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    var mapView: MKMapView
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapView(mapView: mapView)
            CompassButton(mapView: mapView)
                .fixedSize()
        }
    }
}
```

That being said, if you don't truly need a separate reference to the compass view, you can simplify and just add it as a subview to the `MKMapView`:

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        let mapView = MKMapView()
        let button = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapView)
        button.compassVisibility = .visible
        button.frame.origin = .init(x: 10, y: 10)
        mapView.addSubview(button)
        return mapView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) { }
}

struct ContainerView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            MapView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!
Unfortunately this solution forces the user to externalize implementation details.
In our example, managing the state upstream externalizes the internals of `MapView` since `MKMapView` ought to be an implementation detail. Furthermore, one should be able to create a separate compass view for a given map view and the link between them ought to be handled as an internal detail not exposed through the contract.

Comment: If you have additional requirements, I suggest you add them to the question.

Comment: Note that the question is about having one View access the UIView of another. Having two views share an external UIView is a work-around but does not address the question's direct needs.

Comment: So the requirement is that one view has to access the other, but there cannot be any knowledge of this from a shared parent state?

Comment: Certainly, but the shared state is effectively the UIView (MKMapView). In addition, it is worth noting that `makeUIView()` likely expects the creation of a new UIView rather than a reference to an existing UIView which may or may not already exist in the layout beyond the control of this View.

Comment: "likely expects the creation of a new UIView" -- is this assumption based on documentation (honest question)? I understand that it is the semantic reading of the method, but you're already stretching what this system is built to do in standard scenarios.