# How can I access to the class that was created inside other struct

Tags: swift, swiftui

I must say sorry if my question is something silly.
Hi! I'm Swift beginner and I'm trying to make an app that shows some web sites using WKWebView.
After Load the site, I would like to evaluate some javascript. So, I need to check whether the site is completely loaded.

Below is the whole source code.
From the code, the function makeCoordinator inside struct WKWebViewstruct will refer to class Coordinator.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var webView = WKWebViewstruct(url: "https://www.google.com")
    @State var webView2 = WKWebViewstruct(url: "https://www.yahoo.com")

  var body: some View {
      ZStack {
          VStack {
              webView
                  .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9,
                         height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.4)
              webView2
                  .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width * 0.9,
                         height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height * 0.2)
              Spacer()
          }
      }
  }
}
struct WKWebViewstruct: UIViewRepresentable {
    var url: String
    let webView = WKWebView()
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else {
            return WKWebView()
        }
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return webView
    }
    func updateUIView(_ webView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        guard let url = URL(string: url) else { return }
        webView.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
//Show the progress
class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, ObservableObject {
    var parent: WKWebViewstruct
    @Published var IsLoading: Bool
    init(_ parent: WKWebViewstruct) {
        self.parent = parent
        self.IsLoading = false
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Loading Started: Date: \(Date.now)")
        IsLoading = true
    }
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        print("Loading Finished: Date: \(Date.now)")
        print(parent)
        IsLoading = false
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

What I want to ask is that, I want to check whether the IsLoading in class Coordinator is toggled or not. However, the class was not created by me but the struct. How can I access to the IsLoading in Coordinator for each WebView?

Comment: You can’t with a SwiftUI View/UIViewRepresentable. You shouldn’t access the properties of a View from the outside

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899403/accessing-another-uiviewrepresentables-controller-or-uiview/74168046#74168046

Comment: @loremipsum thanks for answering! so... is it means that I cannot access to isloading in View struct directly and should i make alternative class that have bool instance and check the loading completion by using the alternate class?

Comment: Use a shared source of truth like in the example

Comment: @loremipsum Thanks a lot! Your code was worked as I intended! Also, That code give me very useful coding tip, informed the way of good coding. I left thanks here as that answer deleted. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got to see it and it helped.