# Why does adding annotations in the updateUIView method of UIViewRepresentable causes stuttering animations in my SwiftUI app?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am building an app where when the user taps on the bus icon, only bus stop annotations be added on the app. I notice severe stuttering in my view's animations as long as I add annotations in the updateUiView method. ***Once I remove it, the app is buttery smooth.***

Where else can I call this method so that when the user taps on a bus button in swiftUI, only bus annotations are added onto the map?

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        print("Updating MKMapView")

        if lastViewInStack == .nearbyBusStops {
            uiView.removeAnnotations(uiView.annotations) 
            
            //Adding annotations in updateUIView causes stuttering immediately...
            print("Adding annotations")
            uiView.addAnnotations(getLocations(center: uiView.centerCoordinate))
        } else {
            uiView.removeAnnotations(uiView.annotations)
        }

func getLocations(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> [MKAnnotation] {
        var annotations = [MKAnnotation]()
        
        for busStop in nearbyBusStopsViewModel.nearbyBusStops {
            // Create an annotation
            let annotation = BusStopAnnotation(busStop: busStop)
            annotations.append(annotation)
        }
        
        return annotations
    }

class BusStopAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    let busStop: BusStop
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(busStop: BusStop) {
        self.busStop = busStop
        self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: busStop.wrappedLatitude, longitude: busStop.wrappedLongitude)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not a fan of doing work in the “update” function, especially if you have many bus stops. This is another approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569851/execute-function-from-swiftui-view-to-view-controller/77571500#77571500 I am likely in the minority though on here to me it is almost identical to trying to do work in the “body” which shouldn’t be done either.

Comment: The issue is that the MKMapView is shared between multiple view models in my app such as BusViewModel and CarViewModel. Does your approach of creating a weak reference in the view model work in such a case?

Comment: There are many approaches to that  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73899403/accessing-another-uiviewrepresentables-controller-or-uiview/74168046#74168046) is another. It all depends on what you are actually doing. I wouldn’t put an MKMapView in a ViewModel as a source I am a big fan of protocols, I don’t like being tied to a specific anything.

Comment: Is an example possible? The approaches you mentioned are quite difficult and a bit abstract to understand.

I am basically trying to add annotations when the the user press on a "Bus" button after the first launch of the app.

Comment: The second link is as much as a random example that I can provide. Read into Dependency Injection. I use it a lot, SwiftUI people don’t usually mention it but the idea is that you could switch from an MKMapView Provider to any other type rather quickly using protocols.

Answer (score 0):

The trick with `updateUIView` is only add the annotations if you have not already added them before. Treat it like a diff. You can do this either with a boolean in a `Coordinator` or search the map's annotations array if you don't have too many. Currently you are removing and adding new annotations every time `updateUIView` is called which is a major problem. So change it to something like:

```
if lastViewInStack == .nearbyBusStops {
        if context.coordinator.alreadyAddedAnnotations == false {
                uiView.removeAnnotations(uiView.annotations) 
            
                //Adding annotations in updateUIView causes stuttering immediately...
                print("Adding annotations")
                uiView.addAnnotations(getLocations(center: uiView.centerCoordinate))
                context.coordinator.alreadyAddedAnnotations = true
            }
        } else {
            uiView.removeAnnotations(uiView.annotations)
            context.coordinator.alreadyAddedAnnotations = false
        }
```

Also your `makeUIView` must init and return a new instance of `MKMapView`, it can also return it from a lazy property in a `Coordinator` that was init in `makeCoordinator`.